# Not able to add Datasource and Dataset in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am trying to create a new RDLC report in existing project (ASP.Net 4.5). I created new data set (.XSD) successfully, after this added .RDLC file, then I tried to configure the data source and data set. This time I am getting the below error, I googled a lot but didnt get any proper solution, any help highly appriciated.
[image]

Comment: what's the error? the link is empty

Comment: @ninja Please check it now, the link is updated

Comment: Its finding the Yahoo.Yui.Compressor dll

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution to get rid of RDLC throwing errors of third party libraries, temporary try to exclude them and add them back once data set is added.

This is well tested workaround since VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I found an esyest way,
I opened my .Rdlc file in XML mode and I manually added all required tags like

1. DataSources (Provide data source name and connection Properties)
2. DataSets (DataSet Name, Fields - DataField, TypeName)
3. ReportParameters(Name, data types) if any

After doing this I can able to see the fields and data source in Report Data view Data sets and Data source sections.